# How to test a react component which is using an api hook created by redux toolkit query (createAPI) using react-testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I'm using the Redux toolkit query to make an API call from React component. Now the functionalities are working perfectly fine but I'm struggling to write the unit test case for the component using the react-testing library

```
== Redux Toolkit Query API ==

const AssetInstancesAPI = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3003',
    headers: genHeaders(token)
  }),
  reducerPath: 'AssetInstances',
  tagTypes: [`table-contents`],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getAssetsTableData: build.query<any, void>({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: '/assets/summary',
        method: 'get',
        data: body
      }),
      providesTags: [`table-contents`]
    })
  })
});

export const { useGetAssetsTableDataQuery } = AssetInstancesAPI;
```

```
== React Functional component using API hook created by RTK ==

const AssetInstancesTabularView = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetAssetsTableDataQuery(null);

  return (
    <StyledDataTable data-testid='asset-instance-tabular-view'>
      <DataTable title='' selectionMode='multiple' loading={isLoading} data={data?.contents || []} reorderableColumns={true} resizableColumns={true}>
        {!isLoading && data?.columns?.map((column) => <DataTable.Column key={column.field} field={column.field} header={column.header} sortable={true} />)}
      </DataTable>
    </StyledDataTable>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to mock your API call. Use library like https://mswjs.io/ for that. Then you would have something like this:

```
//handlers.ts

import { rest } from "msw";

export const handlers = [
    rest.get("/assets/summary", async (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(
            ctx.status(200),
            ctx.json({
                MOCK_DATA,
            })
        );
    })
]

//browser.ts

export const worker = setupWorker(...handlers);

//server.ts
export const server = setupServer(...handlers);

//setup.ts
beforeAll(() =>
    server.listen({
        //do stuff
    })
);

afterAll(() => server.close());
...


//main.ts
if(USING_MOCK){
  import('./browser')
   .then(({worker}) => {
      worker.start();
   })
   .then(() => {
      root.render(<Main/>);
   });
} else {
  root.render(<Main/>);
}
```